# SQL replace zero 0 values with NULL or text

Tags: mysql, sql, text, replace, null

I have a table Products
Some ProductPrice values are 0 (type is decimal(10,0))

```
ID   | Productname |      ProductPrice                    |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | ShirtXS     |      299                             |
|  2 | TrousersM   |        0                             |
```

ProductPrice is DECIMAL(10,0).
How to write SQL query to convert/replace ProductPrice value 0 with NULL or text N/A?
Desired output:

```
ID   | Productname |      ProductPrice                    |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | ShirtXS     |      299                             |
|  2 | TrousersM   |       NULL or N/A                    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` expression for this:

```
SELECT Productname ,
       CASE WHEN ProductPrice = 0 THEN NULL
            ELSE ProductPrice
       END as ProductPrice
  FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you are looking to `UPDATE` or `SELECT`. If you are looking for `SELECT` you can use `NULLIF()` from MySQL to replace `0` with `NULL`. The syntax is below:

```
SELECT *,NULLIF(<column_name>,0) as <variable_name> from <table_name>;
```